# How to repeat entire nested css animation again

Tags: html, css, animation

I have successfully made my animation banner, but I need to repeat the entire animation from the beginning for an infinite times. But animation iteration count infinite is not working for me because I have individual animations for all my children elements(3 birds, 2 texts). Can anyone help me, how can I repeat the entire animation from the beginning again and again?

[My PEN](http://codepen.io/audhit/pen/qrNxdo)

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="canvas">
  <h2 class="bye">Good Bye</h2>
  <div class="canvas-inner">
   <div class="text">Welcome</div>
    <img class="people" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/9967e45cc8.png" alt="">
    <img class="bird-1" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/996ac926a0.png" alt="">
    <img class="bird-2" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/996bc03236.png" alt="">
    <img class="bird-3" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/996cfb24a4.png" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
margin: 0;
}
.canvas{
background-color: lightgrey;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
position: relative;
left: 30%;
top: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.canvas-inner{
  opacity:1;
  animation-name: final;
  animation-duration: 6s; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-delay: 3s; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }
 .bye{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:120px;
  top: -50px;
  -webkit-animation: bye 2s 6s linear forwards;
 }
 .logo,
 .people{
  position: absolute;
  }
  .text{
   position: absolute;
   right: -100px;
   top: 50px;
   -webkit-animation: text 2s 2s linear forwards;
   }
  .bird-1{
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   -webkit-animation: first 2s linear forwards;
   animation: first 2s linear forwards;
   top: -70px;
   left: 55px;
   }
  .bird-2{
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   -webkit-animation: second 2s linear forwards;
   animation: second 2s linear forwards;
   top: 165px;
   left: -50px;
   }
   .bird-3{
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   -webkit-animation: third 2s linear forwards;
   animation: third 2s linear forwards;
   top: 163px;
   right: -50px;
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes first{
   0%{top: -70px;}
   100%{top:65px;}
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes second{
   0%{left: -50px;}
   100%{left:15px;}
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes third{
   0%{right: -50px;}
   100%{right:135px;}
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes text{
   0%{right:-100px;}
   100%{right:50px;}
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes bye{
   0%{top:-50px;}
   100%{top:110px;}
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes final{
    0%{opacity:1;}
    100%{opacity:0;}
  }
```

Comment: what about animation infinte?

Comment: As I wrote in my question, when I use animation infinite in all the elements the entire thing gets messy :( :( .. I need to loop the entire animation from beginning to end..Right now it is only occurring one time

Comment: Do you need to make animations come one by one infinitely by cycle?

Comment: Banzay, I am not really sure what you mean, sorry. But I need to repeat the entire process for an infinite times. Right now in my pen it is occurring only once. Three birds coming and sitting on the hand, then comes the welcome text, then everything fades out and finally the bye message. So this is one occurrence of my entire animation banner and I want to repeat the whole process infinite times from beginning to end :) .. Hope you are clear now

Comment: You need this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpxYxE?editors=1100  Whole animation cycle takes some time interval, say 8s, so you should define each element's position and animated properties for each step (each second in the interval), thus you just need define state for each keyframe and set it in % of common animation cycle.

Comment: Oh man, super solution!! Excellent, thanks for teaching me this thing,I will work on your solution and get back to you if there is any confusion or problem. Thanks a lot..cheers!